Unable to remount 5TB Hard Drive from JBOD
Unable to remount 5TB Hard Drive
Problem Description
I am using a Debian 12 Server with a RAID controller. The harddrives are all set up with their own Virtual drive in RAID0 JBOD. (so 8 Drives, each with their own Virtual Drive). One of my hard drives was unable to mount after the last restart. When attempting to mount it, the console just "waits" indefinitely without completing the operation.
Hard Drive Specifications

Western Digital 5TB Hard Drive (WD50NPZZ)

Troubleshooting Steps Taken
Below are the outputs from various checks I performed:

Device Identification:

Identified as /dev/sdd. Mounting /dev/sdd1 results in the stall.


SMART Check:

sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdd

smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.1.0-21-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD50NPZZ-00A9JT0
Serial Number:    WD-WXV2EA029SJF
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2be2d94f3
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    5,000,981,078,016 bytes [5.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic
Device is:        Not in smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Jun 10 17:29:14 2024 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                ( 3060) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x1b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 348) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x30b5) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   253   253   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4900
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       57
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   066   066   000    Old_age   Always       -       24896
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       136
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   126   115   000    Old_age   Always       -       26
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     24725         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23465         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported


df Output:

The device is obviously not mounted.


lsblk Output:
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
...
sdd      8:48   0   4.5T  0 disk 
`-sdd1   8:49   0   4.5T  0 part
...


fdisk -l Output:
Disk /dev/sdd: 4.55 TiB, 5000981078016 bytes, 9767541168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD50NPZZ-00A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 38CFA2C8-1A78-4357-8F34-5BDDE5E6B498

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 9767540735 9767538688  4.5T Linux filesystem



Steps Taken to Repair
Filesystem Check

fsck /dev/sdd1 Output:
fsck from util-linux 2.38.1
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
arch21: recovering journal
arch21: clean, 8029/152621056 files, 1122373603/1220942336 blocks



TestDisk Analysis

TestDisk:

Started TestDisk with sudo testdisk /dev/sds, selected the hard drive and [EFI GPT] partition map, and began analysis.
Initial output after the search:

TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sdd - 5000 GB / 4657 GiB - CHS 608001 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>P Linux filesys. data         2048 9767540735 9767538688 [arch21]


<~20 newlines omitted>


Structure: Ok.  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
                P=Primary  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
     Enter: to continue
ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB, 5000 GB / 4657 GiB



Request for Help
I have exhausted the troubleshooting steps to my knowledge and really have no Ideas left. The partition size is reported incorrectly, and I am unable to mount the drive.
Does anyone have any ideas or tips on how to recover or repair this hard drive?
EDIT - requested data
parted -l output:
```
Model: ATA WDC WD50NPZZ-00A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 5001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name    Flags
 1      1049kB  5001GB  5001GB  ext4         arch21


```

The full sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdd output is:
```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdd: 9767541168 sectors, 4.5 TiB
Model: WDC WD50NPZZ-00A
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 38CFA2C8-1A78-4357-8F34-5BDDE5E6B498
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 9767541134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2413 sectors (1.2 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      9767540735   4.5 TiB     8300  arch21

``` 

output of sudo dmesg | grep -C 20 -e arch21 -e sdd1 -e sdd:
```
[616028.173215] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#231 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0

<omitted ~5000 lines with the same output except for [xxxxx.xxxxxx] and tag#xx>

[616256.020279] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#195 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
[616262.282547] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#196 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=362s
[616262.282558] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#196 CDB: Write(16) 8a 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[616262.282562] I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2048 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x20800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[616262.282616] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[616262.282709] EXT4-fs (sdd1): I/O error while writing superblock
[616262.282757] EXT4-fs (sdd1): mount failed
[616262.440133] sd 0:0:13:0: SCSI device is removed
[616262.491021] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[616262.491247] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[616262.492913] megaraid_sas 0000:0b:00.0: scanning for scsi0...
[616271.122959] scsi 0:0:13:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD50NPZZ-00A 1A01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[616271.321365] sd 0:0:13:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[616271.323661] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] 9767541168 512-byte logical blocks: (5.00 TB/4.55 TiB)
[616271.323670] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
[616271.424996] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[616271.425005] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 9b 00 10 08
[616271.426397] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[616271.536188]  sdd: sdd1
[616271.536460] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[616279.922909]  sdd: sdd1
[616280.033973]  sdd: sdd1
[616494.154828]  sdd: sdd1
[616573.862696]  sdd: sdd1

```

output of journalctl -r:
```
Jun 13 14:06:51 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#214 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:51 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#213 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#212 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#211 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#210 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#209 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#208 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#207 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#206 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#205 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#204 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#203 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#202 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#201 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#200 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#199 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#198 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#197 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#196 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#195 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#194 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#193 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#192 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#255 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#254 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#253 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#252 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#251 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#250 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#249 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#248 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#247 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:49 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#246 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:49 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#244 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:49 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#243 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:49 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#242 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
```

Interesting output fromn MegaCli:
I have installed MegaCli and found some more info (I cant really interprate)
Running the command megacli -PDList -a0 gives the following:
(omitted the non relevant disks)
Enclosure Device ID: 62
Slot Number: 7
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 13
WWN: 50014ee2be2d94f3
Sequence Number: 14
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 4.547 TB [0x24630d9b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 4.547 TB [0x24620d9b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 4.546 TB [0x246139800 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  4096
Firmware state: JBOD
Device Firmware Level: 1A01
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221107000000
Connected Port Number: 7(path0) 
Inquiry Data:      WD-WXV2EA029SJFWDC WD50NPZZ-00A9JT0                    01.01A01
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :30C (86.00 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Drive's NCQ setting : Disabled
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No

Intresting to note:
the Device Firmware Level' on all the other drives is 0001`.
the Inquiry Data allways ends with the firmare level, except for this entry, where there is a 01.0 in front.
Running megacli -PhyErrorCounters -a0 results in:
(omitted not relevant drives, they all have 0;0;0;0 as their values)
Phy No: 7 
Invalid DWord Count           : 15 
Running Disparity Error Count : 3 
Loss of DWord Synch Count     : 3 
Phy Reset problem Count       : 0 


What does parted -l show? I think (but am absolutely not sure) that fdisk doesn't play well with GPT drives, so parted -l might be more informative. Also, where did you buy this? Was it in an official store or somewhere else? Could it be that you were actually sold a 500G drive instead of a 5T one?

Ah no, hang on, this isn't a new drive, right? It is one you know for a fact worked and reported 5T until recently?

You mention RAID0, with the implication that this disk is part of the hardware RAID setup. Why are you trying to go anywhere near this drive with mount and fsck? You're unlikely to see any data at all on this disk if it's part of a RAID0, and at worst you'll corrupt whatever data is left so that you can't reinsert it into your RAID array. You can review the SMART attributes but that'll be about all. Talking of which, please do include the results of smartctl -a /dev/sdb. Don't redact anything (except the serial number, if you must)

. Please also detail the USB3 to SATAIII adapter, as some of them are really weirdly broken, and some just don't work at all unless you're using them with Windows systems. In fact, FWIW I'd put my money on the adapter being the thing that's truncating the 5TB disk at 500GB

You show DOS or MBR partitioning. Only gpt can be used when drive is over 2TB. What does sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb show? Also RAID 0 normally not recommended. It was used to speed up HDD, but you can get faster speeds with NVMe drives now. And if any drive in RAID 0 fails you lose everything, so good backups required.

Added the requested data to the end of the main post.
To the question, why did I remove it from the rack/raid controller:
it had the kind of same behavior when connected to the server via. Raid controller.
I will give you the data of all the tests with the hard drive in the original slot of the server. This may take a few hours.
more information about the raid:
The Raidcontoller is set up, that it always takes one Hard drive, and creates a virtual drive (in RAID0) out of it. So there is no "real" striping. That's why I expected to be able to troubleshoot outside the server.

Oh, so it's a single disk RAID0? Please add that to the question, as RAID0 usually implies multiple disks

Inserted the hard drive into the original server. Now the size is reported correctly. Mount still results in a stall, until I restart / reinsert the hard drive.
All output is either from the original server now, or removed / struck, if the problem was "solved"

OK, that's a useless SATA/USB adapter then. Either bin it or return it for a working one

Was there anything in syslog / journalctl / dmesg (after a while) when it stalled?

Your fsck has to be on an ext4 partition like sdd1 not a drive like sdd. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474846/fixing-bad-superblock-on-ssd-drive-is-e2fsck-safe-to-run

@frostschutz added the output on the bottom of the post.

I've installed MegaCli to the server and searched for more info. Added the new information to the end of the post. Sadly i don't really know, how to interpret the info, but it seems bad...
Any further help / recommendations are appreciated.
